# How to solve half screen gone when keyboard open on bottom up edittext in Android?

Tags: android, keyboard, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I will created chatting application like on hangout but problem is that top bar hide on bottom up keyboard on edittext open ??? How can i solved this type of issues.

See actually problems on image
[image]

See original screen this:
[image: I need to output as keyboard open on edittext and also to top bar visible]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this in your activity defination in manifest file

android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"

Comment: Thanks for the comment but not solution properly @Ajit Pratap Singh

Comment: Give me asap answer which you have ?

Comment: @najibputhawala i think both smily image && editext layout you had put alingparentbottom=true ?

Comment: @PankajAndroid I already put on this property of relative layout but not getting solution.

Comment: i am not suggetion you to put this properti but i am asking you that you had used this bottom true property and on above of that layout your r putting smily image

Answer (score 1):

In your activity defination in manifest file

user android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"

And in your layout xml file, use root layout as Relativelayout and keep your bottom bar part as independent of all other views.